# Reporting Services - export to Excel in landscape format?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, landscape

is there a way to export XLS files in landscape format by default?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of Excel, but found with export to PDF that setting the report size to a landscape format changed the orientation.

Comment: Set the report height to 210mm and the width to 297mm.  That is the standard size for an A4 in landscape.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with PDF as well...clicking the print button on the ReportViewer control now says that it is landscape, but exporting to pdf is still portrait format. Did I miss anything?